# How do we construct a homomorphism between a simple R-module and a unitary R-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I don't have a lot of experience with this sort of thing and so I am trying to synthesize a process by which I can understand constructing homomorphisms. In this particular case I want to construct a homomorphism between a simple $R$-module and a unitary $R$-module, where $R$ itself is a ring with identity, where $I_{R} \neq 0_{R}$.

I do know that a non-zero unitary $R$-module $M$ is simple if the only submodules of $M$ are $\left\{0_{R}\right\}$ and $M$. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: I assume that you mean *unital* $R$-module, as in a module $M$ s.t. $1_Rm = m$ for all $m \in M$. Perhaps this is alternatively called *unitary*, but I don't recommend that choice of language, as it brings to mind *unitary matrices*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(1) A simple module $M$ must be cyclic. That is, $M = Rm = \{rm \mid r \in R \}$ for any $m \neq 0 \in M$. Why?

(2) For any module homomorphism $\varphi: M \to N$,
$$
\ker \varphi = \{ m \in M \mid \varphi(m) = 0 \}, 
$$
is a submodule. Why?

(3) A homomorphism $\varphi: M \to N$ is completely determined by $\varphi(m)$, where $m$ is any nonzero element (generator) of $M$. Why?

(4) There are only two possibilities for the image submodule
$$
\operatorname{im} \varphi = \{ \varphi(m) \mid m \in M\}.
$$
What are they? Why?

Comment: (1) Since $M$ is simple, it must be generated by any non-zero element because the subgroup generated by one element of the module must be a submodule. Since there are only two in this case (and I assume it isn't trivial) it has to be $M$ itself, so $M$ is generated by that element. . . maybe that could be simplified (no pun intended).
(2) Since $\ker \varphi \subseteq M$ and it satisfies all the operations of $M$, it must be a submodule.
(3) Please explain
(4) I know $M$ itself is one, what is the other?

Comment: For (3), suppose that $M = Rm$ for some $m \in M$. Any nonzero $m \in M$ will do by (1). We must show that $\varphi: M \to N$ is completely determined by where it sends $m$. Say $n = \varphi(m)$. Now take any $m' \in M$. There is some $r \in R$ s.t. $m' = rm$. Now, $\varphi(m') = \varphi(rm) = r \varphi(m) = rn$, and we have no choice in the matter, assuming that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. What is the image submodule in $\varphi(M) \subseteq N$? Either it's an isomorphic copy of $M$ or it's the $0$ submodule, depending on whether $m$ is in $\ker \varphi$ or not.

Comment: this all makes a lot of sense, thank you for your explanation, I think I have what I need.